# JavaFX Text Double Underline Spacing

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2

I have a label in JavaFX application that i need to apply a double underline too.  I know this aint possible to do with a basic property, but instead i have applied the following css to the label, which gives it a "effect" of a double underline

```
.double-underline {
    -fx-border-color: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-underline: true;
}
```

Now this does give me the effect i want, but i need to if possible, increase the spacing between the text and the actual underline.  How can i do this?

This would be easier if there was a "double" border style that i could apply, but there isnt that i know of

Here is what it looks like now

[image: javafx underline image before]

and i would like it too look more like this

[image: javafx underline image after]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may wrap another layout with bottom border.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can adjust the position of the border with CSS:

```
.double-underline {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-underline: true;

    -fx-padding: 0 0 -1 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: As [Uluk Biy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682495/uluk-biy) says, the above snippet will join the border to the actual underline. So this will do what you want:

```
.double-underline {
    -fx-border-color: black, transparent, black;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0, 0 0 1 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 0 1 0, 0 0 2 0, 0 0 3 0;
}
```

Instead of using an underlined label, configure a double border, and just play with the insets.

Comment: The OP wants to increase the spacing between the text and the actual underline.

Comment: Thank you, i am not quite sure how insets work, but this seems to work.

Comment: As you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) insets allows you to define the distance of the border (one value for the 4 sides or a set of 4 values in this order: top-right-bottom-left, for different values on each side). Each comma-separated value or set of 4 values in the series applies to the corresponding border color.